# My Div container is not responding to any CSS change i make

Tags: javascript, html, css

My main goal is i want my svg which is in a div container to come in from the right side of the screen when it loads, but it wont go off screen nor will it resize or anything and im not sure why. I messed around with it a lot and it seemed that some stuff worked with ".space-ship svg{}" but it only kinda worked.

HTML

```
<div class="space_ship">
   <svg width="1136" height="815" viewBox="0 0 1136 815" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
      (its a lot of paths after this)
   </svg>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="scipt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS

```
.space-ship{
  right:  3000px;
  padding:  1%;
  margin:   1%;
  position:  relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.space_ship svg{
  width: 80vh;
}
```

JavaScript

```
anime({
  targets: '.space-ship',
  right: '0px',
  borderRadius: ['0%', '50%'],
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
```

Comment: You are using an underscore on the html and a hypehn in the css - not sure if thats the issue thought - I still could not see the effects even after correcting hat - which is why I deleted my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS and JS.

```
.space_ship{   /* <---- "_" not "-"  */
  right:  3000px;
  padding:  1%;
  margin:   1%;
  position:  relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```
anime({
  targets: '.space_ship',   // <---- "_" not "-"
  right: '0px',
  borderRadius: ['0%', '50%'],
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this, solve your problem?

```css
.space_ship{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background:yellow;
  position:relative;
}

svg{
  position:absolute;
  animation: kf1 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes kf1 {
  from {top: 0px;right:0px}
  to {top: 200px;right:500px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="space_ship">
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
```